# When the route is a PHP file, the page displays an error. No input file specified

Tags: nginx, laravel-5

**My environment is as follows:**

- Linux version 4.4.0-105-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-060) (gcc version
  5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)) #128-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 14 12:42: 11 UTC 2017
- Nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
- PHP 7.2.13  (cli) (built: Dec 7 2018 16:36:58) ( NTS )
- Laravel 5.6

For historical reasons, I had to use a.php as the route for my project.

When I try to access a.php after the configuration is complete, the page displays: No input file specified.

And when I access the route of a non-php file, it will display laravel's 404 page, it is correct, because this route I did not set

So I think the problem is that the route is on the php file. When the route is forwarded, it seems to have some problems that I don't know. Unfortunately, I can't solve it.

My nginx configuration is as follows：

```
    server {
            listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
            listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

            root /var/www/html/public;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;

            # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name _;

            # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html
            sendfile off;

            # Add stdout logging
            error_log /dev/null;
            access_log /dev/null;

            #static rewrite or try_files

            #core route redirect
            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /404.html {
                    root /var/www/html/public;
                    internal;
            }

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    #include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING  $query_string;
                    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
                    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE  $content_type;
                    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
                    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME  $fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI  $request_uri;
                    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI  $document_uri;
                    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT  $document_root;
                    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL  $server_protocol;
                    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
                    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE  nginx/$nginx_version;
                    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR  $remote_addr;
                    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT  $remote_port;
                    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR  $server_addr;
                    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT  $server_port;
                    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME  $server_name;
                    fastcgi_param HTTPS   $https if_not_empty;
                    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS  200;
                    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY  "";

                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }

            location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|webp|tiff|ttf|svg)$ {
                    expires 2d;
            }
    }
```

I tried modifying the value of cgi.fix_pathinfo in php.ini to 1

Then the error becomes: file not found

Does not seem to have an effect

In addition, my local environment is normal, but I use valet locally, it integrates nginx and made some changes, I can't compare the difference between its configuration and online environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a URI does not correspond to a local file, you have a `try_files` statement in your `location /` block which sends then to the Laravel controller (`index.php`).

URIs ending with `.php` are processed by the `location ~ \.php$` block.

If you want URIs ending with `.php` that do not correspond to a local script file, to also be sent to the Laravel controller, add a `try_files` statement in that block too.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I solved this problem by the following method.

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
     Rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
     Break;
}
```

However, I think your answer is more reasonable.@Richard Smith